# Time Series Model - Device/Customer wise

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, categories, categorical-data

I wanted to build a time series model - ARIMA, LSTM for eg. where I am trying to forecast a single time series column. But I wanted to do it say each customer wise. For instance: customer_name, date, metric is my data. I wanted to forecast what will be the metric for customer1 tomorrow.

The actual question now is: How to include the categorical column customer_name to the model.
I am good building model only with metric column but what I need is the metric for a particular customer.

Comment: - Try Customer Id instead of name in train data  ? Maintain a mapping of a name and id separately

Comment: This seems like a panel data forecasting problem to me where your panel (or longitudinal) data consists of time series on multiple customers. Why do you want to include the `customer_name` column? Don't you want to learn a model that makes forecasts based on the observed past observations of metric? If my interpretation of your question is correct, you have multiple options to build your model ...